# "Login information disallowed" error from google script

Tags: google-apps-script, fetch, fetch-api, basic-authentication, urlfetch

I have been trying to use the UrlFetchApp from apps script to fetch the inventory information from an inventory system API called Salesbinders, for some reason I kept getting login information disallowed error, I have tried different ways I found online but none of them is working, I have also tried to put it on postman and it worked so I am assuming the details I provided should be correct.
Here is the salesbindner API documentation: https://www.salesbinder.com/api/

and here is my code

```
function fetching() {
  
  var USERNAME ='{API KEY}'
  var PASSWORD = '{x}'

  var url ='https://{API KEY}:x@{subdomain}.salesbinder.com/api/2.0/items.json'

  var headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(USERNAME+ ':' + PASSWORD)
  };



let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,headers)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

would appreciate it a lot if anyone can help, I have been stuck with this all weekend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, `headers` is not included in the request as the header. If your URL, `USERNAME` and`PASSWORD` are correct, I think that this might be the reason for your issue.

And also, at UrlFetchApp, `then` is not used. When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function fetching() {
  var USERNAME = '{API KEY}';
  var PASSWORD = '{x}';
  var url = 'https://{API KEY}:x@{subdomain}.salesbinder.com/api/2.0/items.json';
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD)
  };
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers });
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

#### Note:

- This modification supposes that your URL, `USERNAME` and`PASSWORD` are correct. If an error occurs, please confirm them again.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: i did a few more run and it works now thank you so much for your help

Comment: @tomtom Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.